# How to put <s: select...> and <s: textfield> in a single line - struts2?

Tags: jsp, struts2

This is somehow embarrassing.
I'm using Struts2 in a small project of mine. In the JSP, when I put something like this:

```
<s:select list="keywords" key="label.search" name="selectedKeyword"/>
<s:textfield name="searchparams" size="20" cssClass="label"/>
```

I get this (sorry, I'm a new user, so I can't add images):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA2Wg.png

```
--dropdown_--
[              ] < textfield
```

What I want is that the textfield is next to the dropdown, in the same line.
Is there a way to do this without creating my own theme?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Struts2 tags are themed using FreeMarker. You can either change from the default XHTML theme to the simple theme by specifying the following in your struts.properties:

```
struts.ui.theme=simple
```

Or you can override the theme for just those tags by adding the theme attribute as follows:

```
<s:select list="keywords" key="label.search" name="selectedKeyword" theme="simple"/>
<s:textfield name="searchparams" size="20" cssClass="label" theme="simple"/>
```

Here's some [additional information about themes](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-themes.html).

Comment: FYI: use of struts.properties is discouraged.  It's better to define the property in web.xml or struts.xml (if the property needs to be global) for instance after the <struts> tag in your struts.xml put <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />

Comment: Where did you read that it is discouraged? And where would you put the property in web.xml?

Comment: I followed up as an answer just because formatting was an issue.

Comment: Thanks. Are you referring to *Apache Struts 2 Web Application Development* or something else? I've never read anywhere about the struts.properties approach being discouraged and it would be nice to read why it is discouraged.

Comment: Well I said discouraged when all he said was 'not preferred', sorry for knocking the connotation up a notch.  I don't think it is anything more than reducing the number of configuration files.  With the convention plug-in it is conceivable web.xml would be the only xml file you'd need.  Although I still prefer putting configuration in struts.xml and I like creating an xml file for each package, if the length warrants it. Yes it was from that book, it is mentioned in at least two different places.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the clarification. I wouldn't define any of those in web.xml, personally, but struts.xml is also a good place to put it.

Comment: Hi.Thank you all for your answers. I understand your suggestions, but I still have a problem: when I change to theme=simple, my css doesn't load and the same happens to Applicationresources.properties??

Comment: @StevenBenitez Better late than never. The `struts.properties` file is maintained for backwards compatibility with WW, mentioned on https://struts.apache.org/docs/constant-configuration.html. The XML files also allow you to break up config which the property file does not.

Answer (score 1):

**Note for struts.properties not preferred**:

"It's also possible to define constants in our web.xml file; this is useful when we don't need an XML-based configuration. Either is acceptable: which is used depends on your needs and preferences. We can also define constants in a file named struts.properties, also on the classpath, that this is not preferred." - Apache Struts2 pg 21.

**To struts configuration in web.xml**:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>action</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>struts.ui.theme</param-name>
        <param-value>simple</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

**How to set parameter for a whole page**:

Maybe not for everyone but personally if I don't want what ever is the default I will want to use another theme for the whole page, so this is convenient.

```
<s:set var="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />
```

**How to set parameter in struts.xml**:

Just under the root 'struts' tag you can define constants like so...

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```