# Creating jsp pages with struts2 containing forms and other elements

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i am working on a struts2 project. in the view layer i need to create forms which have images, hyper links, text, etc. which are not struts2 component tags. As a result when i try to use both of these in my page they are separated as in the struts 2 form components are displayed separately and images and other stuff are displayed separately. How do i make page in which all these stuff lie within the region of the form without separation or unwanted linefeed.

This is a sample problem......

`<s:form action="xyz.action">
<s:textfield name="name"/>
<img src="abc.png">
<s:textfield name="other info"/>
<s:submit/>
</s:form>`

now what i expect is an image which is displayed between the 2 textfields. but what i get is that image is loaded at  a different location(above the entire form). I will also need to use hyper links text in a similar way.

Comment: You'll need to provide code examples.

Comment: i have provided some code which is sample of what i expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the default theme of struts2, it will decorate the  with some extra tag. So if you want to make the  behave like normal  you have to set the theme to 'simple'. Try this

```
<s:form action="xyz.action" theme="simple">
     <s:textfield name="name"/> 
     <img src="abc.png"> 
     <s:textfield name="other info"/> 
     <s:submit/> 
</s:form>
```

Comment: Vince is correct, this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478750/how-to-put-s-select-and-s-textfield-in-a-single-line-struts2/4481998#4481998 addresses several different ways to set the theme to simple including how to set a theme as the default.